# How to respond in grails with a map of variables and domain objects without double wrapping the domain objects

Tags: grails, groovy, domain-object

In grails I am trying to return parameters back to the ui.  In my controller I respond with a map. The problem I have is the domain objects for example parent and child end up double wrapped.

```
Map paramsdata = [
        child: parent.child,
        parent: parent,
    ]

    respond( paramsdata )
```

so my response is something like this

`"child":{"child":{all properties here}}, "parent":{"parent":{all properties here}}`

This means in the ui I have to do something like response.get('parent').get('parent')

I have tried a lot of different ways to get this to work how I would like but nothing seems to work.

Comment: How exactly would you like it to work?

Comment: Your `ui` is gsp, javascript or other? What is the expected format of the response?

Comment: I want to get a map of two domain objects "child":{all properties here}, "parent":{all properties here}. 

So that I can use javascript and say response.get('parent') and not have to call get('parent') twice.  I use a javascript backbone front end.

The javascript is expecting JSON back and respond is returning everything as JSON.

Comment: Can you show what's in the parent.child and parent variables?

Comment: I can give an example but I am not sure why it is important.  I am just asking basically what is the best way to pass back multiple domain objects back to the UI without double wrapping them.  The Parent object has one child and probably a name and what ever other generic attributes.  These are not the actual objects I am trying to send back to the ui.  I am passing a map of about 10 things and everything comes through just fine except the two domain objects are double wrapped.

Comment: It's important because of what @Aston said in his answer. For both the reason, and his suggestion that there must be a better way.

Answer (score 1):

Your 'parent' and 'parent.child' values are already maps with 'parent' and 'child' entries. So, if on the UI you want it simpler:

```
Map paramsdata = [
    child: parent.child.child,
    parent: parent.parent,
]

respond( paramsdata )
```

But as you can see there must be a way to prevent this before you create your 'paramsdata'.